# Time slicer for different visualisations in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I want to change visualisations with a time period slicer.

[image]

This is an example of a page for a single month of data. I would like to have a time slicer that would allow me to select different months/time periods and show me the relevant data.

I thought about using buttons with bookmarks to be able to click between different months, but it is not feasible when more months come in. All the guides on the internet show how to change visualisations with time as an axis, so I don't know where to look.

Please let me know if there is a better way to do this!

Comment: in order to visualize your data by time, ur data has to have a time column. lets assume you have. My reccomend create a table with a column includes only dates (it can be by day or month etc based on your data)  then create a relation between data's time column and newly created date column... Add a slicer with your newly created date column and u r done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your data sources add separate column for **date** (or you can use existing column for that)

Next you have to create calendar from power bi or insert excel sheet, Its better to create calendar from power bi.

Then you need to make sure all the date columns are in **date format**. And make relationship between columns.
[power bi desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTKnV.png)

Drag and drop created date column to the calendar column.

Then you have global slicer that affect to your selected visualization.

From slicer you can change slicer visualization as you want